# boost interprocess wrapper to allocator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have multi index container in shared_memory

```
//Create hash
typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
  My_Key,
  My_Key_hash_indices,
  bip::allocator<MyKey, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
> MyGlobalHash;
```

I need according to configuration to use one of the following:

1. bip::managed_mapped_file
2. bip::managed_shared_memory

Is there a way to do it without creating both type, like making a wrapper class for the allocator and inherit for both types.

More code at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ea79752512fad8

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need that. A quick static assert learns that the default segment-manager type is the same:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<
        bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager,
        bip::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>{}, "incompatible segments");
```

So, you can just use one:

```
using SegmentManager = bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager;
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e7c25c8cf2d6ffc)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

static_assert(std::is_same<
        bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager,
        bip::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>{}, "incompatible segments");
using SegmentManager = bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager;

struct X {
    int i = 0;
};

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<X,
      bmi::indexed_by< bmi::ordered_unique< bmi::tag<struct byI>, bmi::member<X, int, &X::i> > >,
      bip::allocator<X, SegmentManager>
  >;

void dump(Table const& t) {
    std::cout << "table: ";
    for(auto& x : t)
        std::cout << x.i << "; ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void run_test(Table& table) {
    dump(table);

    if (table.empty()) {
        table.insert({{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}});
    } else {
        table.insert({5});
    }

    dump(table);

    table.erase(table.begin());
    dump(table);
}

int main() {
    {
        bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_or_create, "msm", 10ul<<20);
        run_test(*segment.template find_or_construct<Table>("name")(segment.get_segment_manager()));
    }
    {
        bip::managed_mapped_file segment(bip::open_or_create, "mmf", 10ul<<20);
        run_test(*segment.template find_or_construct<Table>("name")(segment.get_segment_manager()));
    }
}
```

Prints (on my system) e.g.:

```
table: 2; 3; 4; 
table: 2; 3; 4; 5; 
table: 3; 4; 5; 
table: 2; 3; 4; 
table: 2; 3; 4; 5; 
table: 3; 4; 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes i can but the problem is that with the solution you proposed i need to have a wrapper class/function that have both type of pointer and do a if/else according to segment type i need to use - this was my question(Is there a way to do it without creating both type)

Comment: David, I didn't create any wrappers. There's only `Table` which I demonstrate with both segment types without ANY difference

Comment: In my code i have a lot of place that use the table. In the main, if you had to use one or the other type of shared memory you would have to write if(mappped_file)  run_test<bip::managed_mapped_file>("mmf"); else run_test<bip::managed_shared_memory>("msm"); This is what i want to avoid using the if else

Comment: Oh oops. I seem to have copy pasted the not-so-final version of the code. Believe me, I've had many much more complicated versions :) Fixing the answer.

Comment: Ok, all in all there was no cause for alarm. Just a few redundant template parameters that weren't actually being used. I hope it's clearer now.